# pandas How do I delete rows from an ordered dataframe until a specific value appears?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I delete rows in Python/ pandas for each column A until the first C value appears in column B?

input

```
index   | A   | B   |
--------|-----|-----|
0       | X   | A   |  
1       | X   | B   |
2       | X   | C   |  
3       | X   | A   |
4       | X   | C   |
5       | X   | ... |  
6       | Y   | A   |  
7       | Y   | B   |
8       | Y   | C   |  
9       | Y   | A   |
10      | Y   | C   |
11      | Y   | ... |
```

desired output

```
index   | A   | B   |
--------|-----|-----|
2       | X   | C   |  
3       | X   | A   |
4       | X   | C   |
5       | X   | ... |  
8       | Y   | C   |  
9       | Y   | A   |
10      | Y   | C   |
11      | Y   | ... |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you either don't have a second X cluster after the Y cluster (or that you consider all X clusters the same, even if they're discontiguous):

One way would be to compare the column B with C (getting a boolean series of False and True), then groupby the A column.  The cumulative maximum of these will be like False, False, True, True, True where we start getting Trues the first time we see C, and we can use that to index into df.  For example:

```
In [19]: df.loc[(df["B"] == "C").groupby(df["A"]).cummax()]
Out[19]: 
    A    B
2   X    C
3   X    A
4   X    C
5   X  ...
8   Y    C
9   Y    A
10  Y    C
11  Y  ...
```

because

```
In [20]: df["B"] == "C"
Out[20]: 
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

and

```
In [21]: (df["B"] == "C").groupby(df["A"]).cummax()
Out[21]: 
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```